# groupby and standaring name in one column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

got this problem, (i think) i know how to use the groupby things. but i need to standarized this one row(Name)'s element/name inside.

| Name | Fee |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 3 |
| Michael () | 4 |
| Sarah - (0) | 5 |
| Sarah | 5 |

how do i get rid of the (), -, (0), and even spaces in Name row so when i use the groupby and sum function, the output will be something like this:

| Name | Fee |
| --- | --- |
| Michael | 7 |
| Sarah | 10 |

I used something like this:

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['Name'])['Fee'].sum().reset_index()
print(df2.to_string())
```

and of course, the output is not what i was expecting. and actually resulted with the same table it begins with

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, your question does not look like a well posed problem. I read it as "How to get rid of the garbage in the text field of a dataframe?" But how exactly do you define garbage. How would you deal with "X Æ A-12" in the name column?

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thing that comes to my mind -- Regular Expressions.

you can try leaving only alpha characters, to get rid of symbols via code below:

```py
import re

string = 'Sarah - (0)'
clean_string = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z ]+', '', string)
```

This would get rid of symbols and numeric characters;
Now we're left with trailing spaces, which can be removed with `strip()` method:

```py
clean_string = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z ]+', '', string).strip() # strip removes trailing and heading spaces
```

So, if you're dealing with pandas' DataFrame object, you need to wrap this RegEx into a function, and apply it to your column.

Comment: Clarification for regex: `^` means negation, `A-Za-z` means english characters, both upper and lowercase, ` ` space
So we're replacing NOT English characters to empty string, and later removing only trailing and heading blanks with `strip()` (to make sure that double-worded names are left untouched)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for extract word:

```
s = df['Name'].str.extract(r'(\w+)', expand=False)
```

Or multiple words:

```
s = df['Name'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z\s]+\s*)', expand=False).str.strip()
```

and pass to `groupby`:

```
out = df.groupby(s)['Fee'].sum().reset_index()
print (out)
      Name  Fee
0  Michael    7
1    Sarah   10
```